# Connecting an HTML page to Django page

Tags: python, html, django, windows

I need to make a project in which statistics are needed and have to be made with matplotlib. For this I need to use Django, the goal is to create a project in Django that shows you 3 graphics of statistics. The problem is that I need to make it from an HTML page and by pressing a button it redirects you to the Django's that shows the graphics.

I have practically no knowledge in Django, but I know Python. My main problem is how to create that Django web page that executes the graphics script and how to make the HTML reference to the Django page.

Comment: Stack Overflow is meant for specific questions. This is a generic question which is solved easily by watching a tutorial. Also, try to add a sample code to help others to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django is a url oriented framework. You set up the project. Then you create an `app` inside the project. You will have a main `urls.py` which distribute the urls between the app-level urls as you assign. 
Once one the urls are requested, a view (basically a method) is triggered. You can return a html page by the following code:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def some_view(request):
    return render(request, 'some_html.html')
```

Just watch a few tutorials. These are the first things that they cover.